# How do I format an arrow key input?

Tags: support, edits, formatting

As part of an edit, I'm adding `<kbd>` tags to various user keystrokes mentioned in a question. I can't figure out the proper way to handle arrow keys.

<kbd>Left arrow</kbd>?

<kbd><-</kbd>?

<kbd>Left</kbd>?

All the options I can think of seem bad.

Comment: How about `→` and `←`?

Comment: @double-beep Much better. Where do you get those? (Because I need up and down arrows too.)

Comment: Whoops! You need up and down? I copy-pasted this from chat messages. If a RO moves messages then there is a → and the messages that are moved have a ←; try it yourself! A room where there are a lot of messages moved is [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570)

Comment: Just google for "Unicode" and "arrows". Copy, paste, done.

Comment: Found up: ↑ and down: ↓.

Comment: On Linux (Gnome at least): `AltGr` + `Shift` + `U` = `↑`; `AltGr` + `I` = `→`; `AltGr` + `U` = `↓`; `AltGr` + `Y` = `←`, although it probably only works on some keyboard layouts, like on the German one, but with `AltGr` + `Z` = `←` instead.

Comment: [Unicode arrows](http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_arrows.html).

Answer (score 73, accepted):

After searching, I found the arrows you want. Copy-paste each time the appropriate:

```
<kbd>↑</kbd>
<kbd>↓</kbd>
<kbd>→</kbd>
<kbd>←</kbd>
```

Output:

> <kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd>

The arrows can be found in chat or in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_(symbol)#Arrows_in_Unicode).

Comment: You can probably use HTML entities also: `<kbd>&larr;</kbd>` etc.

Comment: Windows Character Map application has a nice selection of characters too: ▲►▼◄ and there are more ☻.

Comment: On Linux computers you can use a compose-key (search your keyboard settings) and then enter at least some arrows directly.

Answer (score 97):

The [HTML entity codes](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) for directional arrows are pretty intuitive:

| Direction | HTML Entity Code | Shorthand HMTL Entity Code | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Up | `&uparrow;` | `&uarr;` | <kbd>↑</kbd> |
| Down | `&downarrow;` | `&darr;` | <kbd>↓</kbd> |
| Left | `&leftarrow;` | `&larr;` | <kbd>←</kbd> |
| Right | `&rightarrow;` | `&rarr;` | <kbd>→</kbd> |

Answer (score 8):

Since this is meta, and people might get scolded and referred to this question in the future if they type <kbd>Left</kbd> instead of <kbd>←</kbd>, I'd like to propose that <kbd>Left</kbd> is just as valid and understandable as <kbd>←</kbd>, and I currently see it being used frequently.

Personally, I prefer the clarity of reading the word <kbd>Left</kbd> instead of the standard arrow symbol with its narrow head. The added convenience of not having to copy/memorize the arrow symbols when typing makes a big difference when writing as well (not that `&larr;` is all that hard to memorize). Being inside a `<kbd>` is more than enough context to indicate that you're referring to the left *arrow*.

Comment: I don't know about that... when I see "Left", the first thing I would think is "left _what_?". An arrow that points left is a lot more clear.

Comment: @coldspeed My exposure to instructions where keys on the left vs right matter is limited (such as in remote viewers), but to me, If the text doesn't explicitly specify "left _what_", as in `<kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd>`, or `<kbd>Left ^</kbd>`, it's clear to me that it's referring to the left arrow. But again, I don't have any exposure to documentation where `<kbd>Left</kbd>` could be ambiguous.

Comment: @RToyo For many of the users on this site, English is not their first language, and so arrows would be more readily understandable to them (as well as to those of us for whom English is our first language).

Comment: If "Left" were just as valid and understandable as "←", maybe I would have seen at least one keyboard with that style of label on its arrow keys. I can't remember having seen any such thing, so either it's vanishingly rare, or I have repressed the memory.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I have never seen "Left" written on a keyboard either, but I've also never seen a keyboard whose arrows have a shaft as long as the arrow in the <kbd> tag either. Nor have I seen the full spelling of "control" on the ctrl key. Some keyboards also don't write "tab" on the tab key, or "caps lock", or "page up/down", or "backspace", etc, in favour of icons. Keys on a keyboard only have a couple centimetres to portray a key, but fortunately our answers on Stack Exchange can be a little bit larger...

Answer (score 4):

On Windows 10, you can use Alt+NumPad codes for this: `Alt+24` for `↑`, `Alt+25` for `↓`, `Alt+26` for `→`, and `Alt+27` for `←`.

**Beware of "Unicode arrows" sites**: some of the arrows they feature won't display properly on some mobile devices (some didn't on my 2017 Samsung phone), and probably won't on older systems either.

The above ones work 100% of the time AFAIK.

Comment: That should be Alt + NumPad 2 + NumPad 4, etc., since they don't work with the top row numbers. Also, those key combinations enter a Unicode sequence which results in an arrow (8593 in the case of up arrow). As far as "Unicode arrows" sites, [the official site for Unicode is a good place to start](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2190.pdf) :)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Edited to make it clear(er) that Alt codes in Windows use the numpad. Re: Unicode, I know these arrows are Unicode, but they are only 4 and they work. Unicode sites present you with hundreds of different arrows, and you might pick the wrong ones.

Answer (score 3):

This looks close

<kbd>▲</kbd>
<kbd>◄</kbd><kbd>▼</kbd><kbd>►</kbd>

For copy/pasting:

```
<kbd>▲</kbd>
<kbd>◄</kbd>
<kbd>▼</kbd>
<kbd>►</kbd>
```

Comment: Our princess would surely not live in that castle.

Comment: @CodyGray - Sorry, I should have included the flag pole for you in there. Next time.

Comment: I think these are much clearer than the arrows suggested above, especially if your eyesight is failing. Could you [edit] and add the code formatted markdown code for those arrows, please? I tried to click the edit link to see the actual markdown but "Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites."

Comment: @Greenonline - Those are just unicode arrows wrapped in `<kbd>`. You can copy the text for them, for example ▼, and then just use <kbd>▼</kbd>